# Permutation for mostly balanced bipartitions

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation, heuristics

I'm working on a tree search algorithm where I use bipartitions of elements represented via a bitset, i.e. the bitset `1000101` represents the bipartition `{0,2,6} {1,3,4,5}`.

At the moment, I iterate through all bipartitions simply by incrementing a bitset, i.e. to iterate through all bipartitions of the set `{0,1,2,3}`, I go from `0001` (inclusive) to `1000` (exclusive)

Since my algorithm sometimes allows me to 'fail fast' when I have found a suitable bipartition, I want to reorder them such that I look at more balanced bipartitions first.

Thus, I wanted to ask if someone knows of a permutation of the numbers from 1 to 2^k where min(#set bits, #unset bits) more or less only decreases, *which can still be computed efficiently*.

Since this is a heuristic, I'm not looking for exact results, only a way to speed up my algorithm a bit.

Comment: Is there a particular speed you are looking for? Finding the next partition with the same number of set bits is an order `k` operation. You could use that to go through all the `k//2` partitions, then `k//2-1`, etc. Is that fast enough?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, a *Gray code* might help (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code ). The section on *monotonic Gray codes* seems like it might be relevant.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks a lot, your comment definitely lead me into the right direction.

Comment: @JohnColeman While these monotonic Gray codes seem to be a bit more complex to compute, funny enough I was already thinking about using regular Gray codes to minimize the amount of elements to move around. Even though I can't leverage that property in my case, it's always nice to know these codes.

So thank you, too, your comment was quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rory's comment took me in the right direction:

If we start with a fixed number of ones in the bitset, we can simply iterate over all of them using some bit-twiddling hacks.

- Start from `0...01...1` first with `k/2` ones, then with `k/2 - 1`, `k/2 - 2` and so on.
- For each starting value, iterate over all possible permutations of the bitset using [Gosper's Hack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) until we reach the boundary of our bitset.

A simple implementation might look like this (for `k <= 63`)

```c
for (int i = k / 2; i > 0; --i) {
    // start with 0 ... 0 1 ... 1 (i times)
    unsigned int v = (1 << i) - 1;
    // first bitset that doesn't represent a valid bipartition
    unsigned int end = 1 << k;
    // without this, we would count some bipartitions twice for k even
    if (k % 2 == 0 && i == k / 2) end >>= 1;
    while(v < end) {
        // do something with v...
        // iterate to the lexicographically next permutation
        unsigned int t = v | (v - 1);
        v = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
    }
}
```